# Timer with Target Day to show Alert

Tags: timer, nsdate, alert

I have an app written here is set a fixed reference Day,after this day i want to  get an Alert !

with this code I set the date and time : here Day 3 (Thuesday) and hour 11.
this works great! with an Timer in viewDidload  my navigationItem.title shows Day/Hour/Minutes to the target day...

now i will set a Timer to this Day/Time, when i open my app after Thuesday  (Wednesday or Thursday) the timer is 0 and the Alert shows!

with :

```
NSString *currentTimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", [resetTime timeIntervalSince1970]];
_epochTimeer.text = currentTimestamp;
```

i convert the Target time to epoch Time for my timer!

```
- (void) resetTimer:(id)sender {

        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        [gregorian setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

        NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

        [nowComponents setWeekday:3]; //2 = Monday 3 di 4 = mi 5 = do 6 = fr 7 = sa
        [nowComponents setWeek: [nowComponents week]+ 1 ]; //Next week [nowComponents week] + 1]
        [nowComponents setHour:11]; //8a.m.
        [nowComponents setMinute:0];
        [nowComponents setSecond:0];

        NSDate *resetTime = [gregorian dateFromComponents:nowComponents];



        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"];
        NSDate *date1 = today;
        NSDate *date2 = resetTime;
        NSTimeInterval interval = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];

        int days = (int)interval / 86400;
        int hours = (interval / 3600)-   (days  * 24);
        int minutes =    ((interval / 60) - (days * 24 * 60) -(hours * 60));
        int sekunden = (days * 86400) + (hours * 3600) +(minutes * 60);

        NSString *timeDiff = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d Tage : %02d Std : %02d Min",days, hours, minutes];

        self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",timeDiff];


       NSString *currentTimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", [resetTime timeIntervalSince1970]];


        _epochTimeer.text = currentTimestamp;


        NSLog(@"timer: %@",timeDiff);
        NSLog(@"timer: %@",currentTimestamp);
}
```

how can I set my timer with this epoch time or the target Day/time?
i am a beginner with timer and NSDate and I do not understand how I can write the code!

or is there a completely different solution to get my Alert after the Target day when i open my APP!

Thanks Jürgen

Sorry for my bad English ..:-)

---

Thanks for Helping, i Add your Code and Set the localNotification.fireDate to  resetTime:

```
- (void) resetTimer:(id)sender {

        NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        [gregorian setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

        NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

        [nowComponents setWeekday:7]; //2 = Monday 3 di 4 = mi 5 = do 6 = fr 7 = sa
        [nowComponents setWeek: [nowComponents week]]; //Next week [nowComponents week] + 1]
        [nowComponents setHour:9]; //8a.m.
        [nowComponents setMinute:25];
        [nowComponents setSecond:0];

        NSDate *resetTime = [gregorian dateFromComponents:nowComponents];



        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"];
        NSDate *date1 = today;
        NSDate *date2 = resetTime;
        NSTimeInterval interval = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];

        int days = (int)interval / 86400;
        int hours = (interval / 3600)-   (days  * 24);
        int minutes =    ((interval / 60) - (days * 24 * 60) -(hours * 60));
        int sekunden = (days * 86400) + (hours * 3600) +(minutes * 60);

        NSString *timeDiff = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d Tage : %02d Std : %02d Min",days, hours, minutes];
       _showTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",sekunden];

        self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",timeDiff];


       NSString *currentTimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", [resetTime timeIntervalSince1970]];



        destinationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1425981600];


        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.fireDate =resetTime;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];


        NSLog(@"timer: %@",timeDiff);
    NSLog(@"timer: %@",currentTimestamp);

}
```

and this for my Alert :

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
        // code to display an alert here

        SCLAlertView *alert = [[SCLAlertView alloc] init];
        alert.backgroundType = Blur;
        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:52/255.0 green:222/255.0 blue:192/255.0 alpha:255/255.0];
        [alert showCustom:self image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"geist"] color:color title:NSLocalizedString(@"Auto Reset", nil) subTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Automatischer Reset Aktiviert!", nil) closeButtonTitle:@"OK" duration:0.0f];


}
```

when the time has expired and i start my App ... the Alert is not and it does not happen..

I need to do is activate the Notification somewhere?

thanks

---

Ok i have added your code now in the AppDelegate.m

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{

                UIAlertView* alert= [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"My App"
                                                              message:@"Reset"
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];

        }}
```

now it works, when i start my app the Alert shows, but it Loop Blinking and i can't Klick OK!

what is this now...?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using [NSLocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194)

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
 localNotification.fireDate =<target date>;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
// code to display an alert here
}
```

Comment: Ok i have added your code now in the AppDelegate.m

now it works, when i start my app the Alert shows, but it Loop Blinking and i can't Klick OK!

what is this now...?